# php выводит квадратик вместо 1-го символа?

Tags: php, строки, kohana

Вывожу 1-ый символ строки, получаю вот такой символ �

```
$user->profile->lstname[0]."."
```

При все при этом если всю строку вывести, то она нормально отобразится.

Да, еще так можно решить:

```
Text::limit_chars($user->profile->firstname,1,".")
```

Comment: Проблема-то не в Kohana. Почитайте про строки в UTF8, в них 2 бита просто ))) Юзайте mb_ функции и будет вам счастье!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В UTF-8 с символами всё не так просто.

```
UTF8::substr($user->profile->lstname, 0, 1).".";
```